# Scrub filesystem to check all used sectors are readable

Tags: filesystems, data

I'd like to have a way to periodically check that I can indeed read all the data on my drives, so I can re-write any files and/or investigate further if there is an issue.

Both ZFS and Btrfs have a scrub command for this purpose.

How do I efficiently go about scrubbing ext* and NTFS?

Comment: Why not run `smartctl -t long` occasionally?

Comment: I suspect inspecting sectors regularly does not help SSD longevity.

Comment: @meuh could do. `partclone` on an unmounted partition would be quicker. The issue would then be manually converting sectors to filenames.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro [This](https://www.compuram.de/blog/en/the-life-span-of-a-ssd-how-long-does-it-last-and-what-can-be-done-to-take-care/) says that reading doesn't affect SSD life. Sadly, my budget is spinning rust :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to simply read each file, expecting a message on STDERR if there is a problem:

```
(cd /mountpoint && find . -type d -o -type f -printf '%P\0' | xargs -0 b2sum -z) 2>errors | tee hashes
```

(cd /mountpoint && find . -xdev -print0 | xargs -0P4 xxhsum ) >hashes 2>errors

Using `-z` with `b2sum` (or `sha256sum`) allows for filenames with newlines.

This purposefully includes directories to allow for empty directories.

---

If empty directories aren't an issue, this is shorter:

```
(cd /mountpoint && sha256deep -0clrz -j0 -of . ) 2> errors | tee hashes
```

This will print the filesize, hash, and filename followed by a `NUL`.

Ideally, I'd add `-t` to `sha256deep` but there's currently [this issue](https://github.com/jessek/hashdeep/issues/388).

Comment: Maybe coupling this with regular backups that monitor for file changes.